# Outlook folders constantly rearranging themselves

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I've been using Outlook at work for a while, but all of the sudden it started behaving very strangely. It frequently rearranges my folders on the left; for example, say it looks like this:

1. Inbox
2. Sent Items
3. Deleted Items

When I click on inbox, suddenly this happens:

1. Sent Items
2. Deleted Items
3. Inbox

...and it selects Sent Items instead. Then when I click on Inbox again, it shuffles back to the top.

This also happens without my interaction; I've watched them rapidly switch positions on their own, constantly shuffling around before finally settling. The most consistent behavior is when I click on a subfolder, it shuffles about and select Sent Items instead, which makes it almost impossible to see subfolder emails.

Comment: Weird, but Googling shows you're not the only one running into this at least.  Have you tried running `outlook /resetnavpane` yet?  Are you running any Outlook add-ins?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I'm just on vanilla Outlook, freshly installed.

Comment: @twchapman, is this happening over **office365** ? I have noticed this few times on my outlook too but they were not major so never really gave a thought

Answer (score 4):

Collided with this same problem today. Not sure why and how exactly, but the following solution worked for me just fine... After my Inbox folder (with numerous sub-folders) moved itself once again to a random position I did right mouse click on that folder (Inbox in my case) and used "Move Up" and "Move Down" options from drop-down list to manually move the Inbox folder to the needed position.
After using "Move Up" and "Move Down" options from the "right mouse click" drop-down menu the folder pane seem to stabilized itself and is not rearranging itself any more.
Please try. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for months and this simple step fixed it for me.  I put the **Inbox** back where I wanted it, then I **right-clicked** the Inbox and hit “**Open in New window**”.   That seems to have cleared something, out because after I closed that window, the inbox never moved again.

If it reverts again, I will probably try turning off Cached Exchange Mode, which someone else recommended below, but so far, this solution seems to have cleared the re-sort problem.

Comment: After having tried all the other tips here, this is what finally worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this one worked for me:

right click the account(above the inbox earlier) and click sort subfolders A-Z.
Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Answers that contain the phrase, "Let me know if this helps!" or "this one worked for me:", are not helpful in my opionion.

Comment: Worked initially for me, but then reverted to the wrong order again

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is becoming so common, apparently no solution at all, Microsoft KB's solution tried and tested but of no use but here is a work around that worked for me , try this

You will have to delete the Conversation history folder(if you have any) completely,  empty recycle bin and then restart - This solution worked for me and also for some other users -

Let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Cached Exchange Mode. File > Account Settings > Change > Use Cached Exchange Mode.  This is the only solution that seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Seems to be a problem between synchronise offline cache and server version. I was able to solve this via:

Comment: Seems to be a problem between synchronise offline cache and server version. I was able to solve this via:
1. Disable Cached Exchange Mode and Restart Outlook
2. Order the Folders as you want and wait a minute (or sync manually)
3. Reenable Cached Exchange Mode and restart Outlook. The Order should be good now
4. If not: Delete Outlook Profil and reload the mailbox from scratch. 
---
Solved at >20 Workstations and multiple shared mailboxes

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this on a O365 account using Outlook 2019. The solution for me was to press the sort subfolders by A-Z option. They were already sorted A-Z but pressing this seemed to reverse that setting and Inbox & Sent Items are now showing at the top of the list. Someone else has advised this too, but I'm new and couldn't upvote their reply.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and a [help].